# WiFi is not Available on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, dell

I have been using Windows XP since past 9 years and I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 today for my project purpose.
But I am facing a problem..I am not able to connect to my WiFi connection not is there any setting pertaining to WiFi (enabling nor Connecting).WiFi is working fine with XP.
I have a Dell Inspiron n1545 laptop with Intel Core2duo processor and Dell Wireless Card.
Would Some1 be able to help me with this.?

Comment: Which wireless card do you have?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Plug in the bootable Ubuntu live USB or insert the live CD.
2. Go to System Settings → Softwares and Updates
3. Go to Additional drivers tab. A list of drivers will be loaded.
4. Select your wireless driver, apply changes and you are done!

Comment: Why should he start from a live USB/CD? The system is already installed. I think the first point is unnecessary.

Comment: because it is where the driver is. skipping the 1st point didn't list any device driver on my PC.or you could download and install the driver manually from the internet if you know which device it is.